# How do I prevent the Photos application from launching when my iPhone gets plugged in?

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone

Whenever I plug in my iPhone, iTunes and Photos launch automatically.

I was able to prevent iTunes from launching by going to iTunes->preferences->devices->check box "prevent automatic syncing of iphone"

However, the Photos app does not appear to have a preferences menu (it is greyed out and not clickable from the menu bar), as shown below:

[image: screenshot of launched app and grey preferences]

Anyone know how to prevent this thing from launching every time I plug in my phone?

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I am on 10.10.3

Comment: Just a note about the preferences menu item. It's only accessible once you follow the "Get Started" button visible in your screenshot. However, even then there's no option to disable automatic launch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I searched for "mac action on iphone connection"
and found [How to Keep iPhoto from Launching
When Connecting Your iPhone to Your Mac](http://www.wikihow.com/Keep-iPhoto-from-Launching-When-Connecting-Your-iPhone-to-Your-Mac), which says,

1. Connect your iPhone to your computer. Close iPhoto when it opens up.
2. Open your applications folder and launch the "Image Capture" app. This app detects when you connect a camera (or camera-containing device, such as your iPhone) to your Mac. At the bottom of the window will be a box with your device name. If the box isn't visible, click the little triangle at the bottom left.
3. Select the "No application" option from the menu under the phrase "Connecting ... Phone opens:". This tells your system to no longer open iPhoto as soon as your phone is connected.
4. Quit Image Capture. When your phone is connected again, iPhoto will no longer open automatically.

Comment: Hi Cheers, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I only had to read the first 5 lines of this answer to resolve my problem. The setting exactly where cheers said it would be, and did exactly as he advertised, solving my problem. I'm OK with the link as it provides extra information above and beyond the already well written and complete answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for the "Manually manage music and videos" option since videos taken with the iPhone are stored within the same folder(s) that pictures are. To enable/disable "Manually manage music and videos", select your iPhone device within iTunes, make sure you're looking at "Settings-->Summary" and you'll find it under "Options".